# Wi-Fi Connection Not Working

Tags: wifi, lumia-925, internet

I have my phone connected to Wi-Fi, but it just says "We can not connect to internet try sometime after."

I have tried the following steps but it doesn't help anything:

1. Turn off Bluetooth
2. Turn off airplane mode
3. Reset Wi-Fi connection
4. Restart phone

Comment: Have you tried connecting with another device to ensure it's not a network problem?

Comment: Is this a paid WiFi hotspot, a domestic router, or a company network?

Comment: If the problem is only with your network, try restarting your router.